# What's the best way to implement ACLs to a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acl

I just wanted to compare different solutions used when implementing ACLs in Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the authorization plugin (Created by [Bill Katz](http://www.billkatz.com/)):

> Roles can be authorized for the entire application, a model class, or a specific object. The plugin provides a way of checking authorization at the class or instance method level using permit and permit? methods. It also provides english-like dynamic methods like "user.is_manager_of project" (where "user" acts as authorized, "manager" is a role, and "project" is an authorizable model). You can specify how control is redirected if authorization is denied. ([quote source](http://www.vaporbase.com/postings/Authorization_in_Rails))

Homepage:
http://www.writertopia.com/developers/authorization

Docs:
http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin/tree/master/authorization/README.rdoc

---

You might also be interested in reading this comparison (from last year but still somewhat useful; it's where I got the above quote from):
http://www.vaporbase.com/postings/Authorization_in_Rails

And a more recent comparison:
http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/08/rails-authorization-plugins/

Answer (score 2):

The best I've found is [role_requirement](http://github.com/timcharper/role_requirement/tree/master).  It plugs straight into the restful_authentication plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin called acl_system2 which operates by having a users table and a roles table. There's a lot more useful information in the [README](http://github.com/ezmobius/acl_system2/tree/master/README) and the project is on github too.